# How do I put a banner image behind the navigation bar of my website?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble putting the banner image behind the navigation bar of my website. It keeps putting it below the navigation bar, but I want it to be behind the navigation bar instead.

Here is my code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 89px;
}

nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(28, 28, 28, 0.4);
  width: 1368px;
  height: 89px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 37px 33px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 15px;
}

ul .search-container {
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  padding-right: 41px;
}

::placeholder {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #1c1c1c;
}

ul input[type=text] {
  width: 382px;
  height: 38px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #1c1c1c;
  background-color: #ffb606;
  background-image: url("Images/Search.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 10px;
  padding: 14px 45px 14px 45px;
}

button {
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}

#CartIcon {
  padding-right: 31px;
}

#AccountIcon {
  padding-right: 44px;
}

.SpecialOffer {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.background {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 426.5px;
  background-image: url("Images/Banner.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container">
      <a href="home.html" title="Home"><img src="Images/Logo.jpg" alt="Logo" width="152 px" height="87px"></img>
      </a>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="home.html" title="Home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" title="Products">Products</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" title="About">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
          <div class="search-container">
            <form action="/action_page.php">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="search">
            </form>
          </div>
          <button type="submit"><a href = "#"><img src = "Images/Cart.png" id = "CartIcon"></a></button>
          <button type="submit"><a href = "#"><img src = "Images/Account.png" id = "AccountIcon"></a></button>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div class="SpecialOffers">
      <div class="background">

      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

If there is someone who can help me solve this issue, that will be great. Thanks!

Comment: `<img>` is an empty tag. As such it has not closing tag. `</img>` tag does not exist!!!

Comment: @tacoshy oh i didn't realise i put a closing tag for the Logo image, thanks for reminding me!

Comment: With the code you provided, I'm unable to reproduce the issue you describing. It is unresponsive and only works in fullscreen for me. However the images are inline as expected.

Comment: @tacoshy but how would you work on this, if you were in my position? without using the code I did?

Comment: I would use flexbox. The only browser that does not fully support flexbox is IE. IE however will be started to be deprecated next month by Microsoft itself. So literally no reason to support it IE any further at this point. The responviness issues should be addresses within media queries at the breakpoints itself.

Comment: oh, i'm using Google Chrome as my browser. Do you mind giving me an example of the flexbox code for elaboration? @tacoshy

Comment: [a complete guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) and [W3School Flexbox guide](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

Answer (score -1):

The img tag comes by default with a line break. Try setting the img style to "display:inline" or inline-block. This should eliminate the line break

Comment: the default value of an image is `inline` (most UA treat it as `inline-block` though). Image is an inline-element and as such also not create a line break by default which is cause by block-level elements only.